# jquery onclick or onchange on different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select menu and two arrows for changing the values of the select (+/-). Today, I have a function triggering on a click on the arrows, which updates the value in the select but I would also like to add a function to do the same if someone changes the value directly in the dropdown (instead of using the arrows).

I could re-write the same function and simply change the ID of the arrows to the ID of the select and change the `onclick` to `onchange` but that would be redondant. I would prefer to use a OR operation and have the function written only once.

Is there a way do do a OR operation between two events?

Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img[id*="downArrow"]').on("click", function(){
     //update the value in the select
   });
});
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[id*="downArrow"]',#idOfMySelect).on("click onchange", function(){
         //update the value in the select
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine them using a comma between the selectors and no comma between the events.

You'll need to be careful though, because you probably don't want to trigger the function when the `select` element is clicked:

```js
$('img[id*="downArrow"], #mySelect').on('click change', function(e) {
  if(e.type==='change' || this.id!=='mySelect') {
    alert('Success!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="downArrow" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were going in the right direction just a typo "change" instead of "onchange"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[id*="downArrow"]',#idOfMySelect).on("click change", function(){
         //update the value in the select
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single method on 2 listeners. Example:

```js
function onEventFunction(e){
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img[id*="downArrow"]').on("click change", onEventFunction);
});
```